# ADS "required reviewer" policy for pull requests: "any of" or "all of"?

Tags: azure-devops

If I add a "required reviewer" policy to a branch, and that policy has multiple people in it (or a group that consists of multiple people), is it that "any of" the reviewers is sufficient to satisfy the policy or is it that "all of" the reviewers must accept to be sufficient?

I'd really prefer it to be "any of" for our purposes.

Answer (score 1):

> ADS "required reviewer" policy for pull requests: "any of" or "all of"?

To resolve this request, you could add those reviewers in to the a project team `ReviewerGroup`:

[image]

Then add this team as required reviewer, there is an options **Minimum number of reviewers** when we add this group as reviewer:

[image]

Then, when one or more of the reviewers in the team approve, the policy is met and the PR can be completed.

You could check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#automatically-include-code-reviewers) for some more details.